# Using ng Repeat inside a custom directive to populate a select dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was having a trouble populating a selected dropdown with an ng Repeat inside a custom directive. I've found this example that looks very similar to what I want to achieve http://plnkr.co/edit/W1MMx7vjKKXFuV8LbBjJ?p=preview. It seems to work, but not mine though.

**The goal**: Get the select dropdown to display array of options from a testArray

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/XMwFKTYRgqYzOcsUMDEp?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.testArray = [{'option' : '1' }, {'option': '2'}, {'option': '3' }];
  $scope.testModel = {};
});

app.directive('testDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      dataHeldmodel: '=',
      dataOptions: '='
    },
    template: '<select name="dataHeldmodel" data-ng-model="dataHeldmodel">' +
                    '<option value="">Select</option>' +
                    '<option value="{{option.option}}" data-ng-repeat="option in dataOptions">{{option.option}}</option>' +
                '</select>',
    replace: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body data-ng-controller="mainController">
    <test-directive data-options="testArray" data-heldmodel="testModel"></test-directive>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working plnkr with ng-repeat:
http://plnkr.co/edit/MP2C1VDi9YlM1HBDsbO2

Change data to dat:

```
scope: {
  datHeldmodel: '=',
  datOptions: '='
}
```

and

```
<test-directive dat-options="testArray" dat-heldmodel="testModel"></test-directive>
```

It seems 'data' as an attribute is reserved.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Brilliant, mate. So weird, cus data-heldmodel worked just fine, but it was an issue for ng-options.

Comment: It seems that ng-model isn't populated though

Comment: Yes I have. Perhaps my issue is of a different kind. I've got a custom directive in a repeater, one for input, one for select. They are displayed based on some object properties. If there is 'unit' as an object property display input, if there is 'options' display select dropdown. My base ng-model is userData = {}. 
`Obj in a repeater: [{'tankVolume': { options: {'option1' : '1', 'option2': '2', 'option3': '3' }},
    'tankRating': {unit: '%'}}]`
How could I pass a property of an object into ng-model like this ng-model="userData.[prop name]".
Expected:
userData.tankVolume
userData.tankRating

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to do something like this: 

    <div ng-repeat="obj in objects"> <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in obj"> <test-directive dat-options="val.options" dat-heldmodel="testModel[key]"></test-directive> </div> </div>

Comment: Alternatively you could make another plnkr, that shows your problem.

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted to do. However I was getting back ng-model="testModel.datHeldmodel" instead of ng-model="testModel.tankVolume".
BTW, you can just do <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in objects">
I appreciate it's not very clear, I will make a plunker to illustrate the problem asap.

Answer (score 1):

Try using default `ng-options` directive to solve this problem like this.

```js
<select ng-model="testModel" ng-options="obj.name for obj in testArray track by obj.id"></select>
```

Comment: Did you actually make it work or just gave it a guess? obj doesn't have an id property in testArray. Yes. I tried that before and got the same result.

Comment: I did make it work in my application. But i didn't try your code. I just gave an example.

Comment: @YaroslavS120, you may have error with `testModel`. You should set `testModel` like this. `$scope.testModel = $scope.testArray[0];`

Comment: Are taking into account my requirement about binding data to a select dropdown inside a custom directive?

Comment: `$scope.testModel = $scope.testArray[0];`this snippet is with the `ng-options`. You may get `ng-options`error because you didn't set `testModel` correctly.